# Making a QWidget fill 100 of its parent

Tags: qt, qt5

Im trying to create a Qt application where I want a QWidget to fill 100% of the main-window, and ocasionally I want two widgets side by side. I've setup a layout on the main-window and tried to write:
`QMainWindow::centralWidget()->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Which worked, but had a weird 1px border to the left and the top. I then tried: `QMainWindow::centralWidget()->layout()->setSpacing(0);` in combination with with `setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` but it still has that 1px border. I tried to set the position to `(1, 1)` but that just moved the line to the bottom and right, so it seems like the window is being oversized by 1px.

Does anyone know the answer to why this is happening?

[image: Image of the application]

(The widget is red and the background is black)

Comment: Is it a plain old `QWidget`, or is it a class derived from `QWidget`? I ask because some derived classes have borders or shadow effects that could be to blame.

Comment: @Carlton It's a plain QWidget, though I have tried to remove the borders, but that didn't work.

Comment: Off topic but... if all you ever want is one or two widgets that fill their parent completely then why use `QMainWindow`?  A plain `QWidget` might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to answer without working example or more info. It may be caused by OS rendering system, math-alignment (how is created the rectangle?), scalling/dpi etc.